# Where did Mr. Freeze go to school?

Tags: dc, batman, mr-freeze

Mr. Freeze (Dr. Victor Fries) was actually a doctor.  I believe he went to medical school but I could be wrong on that.  Is there any information on which school he attended or alternatively which school(s) he taught at?

Comment: He's not a medical doctor, he has a doctorate in cryogenics; https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSnYD.jpg

Comment: Also worth noting that there are multiple versions of the Mr Freeze backstory.  I'm not sure that *any* of them specify his alma mater, but there are certainly significant conflicts between some of them.  You migth want to clarify which version you mean.

Comment: Good point.  I know at least in one he was a medical doctor.  Honestly I'm just interested if in *any* of the versions either his alma mater or where he taught (if applicable) was specified.  It's honestly just for a super lame joke but I couldn't find this information specified anywhere.

Comment: @Dason - I've looked at his backstories across a range of comics and media. In the modern era (after he was retconned into a real doctor) it's repeatedly mentioned that he has a doctorate but I've not seen any confirmation where he got it.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly where, but I do know he worked some shifts at McDonald's to support himself. If you imagine Arnold Schwarzenegger saying _DO YOU WANT FRIES WITH THAT?_ it makes total sense.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - It would also explain why the ice cream maker is always broken if he needs to steal the freon.

Comment: Kids these days. [He went to Universität Wien](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otto_Preminger).

Comment: It's obvious... he went to school in Iceland.